how to extract this value within soup body
here is my python code that does a BeautifulSoup on a API Call response content:
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'lxml')

and if I output the soup body, it looks like this:
<html> 
<body>
.... 
<script src="/site_media/js/jquery/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script nonce="" type="text/javascript">
  var username_field = document.getElementById("id_username");
  if(username_field.value){
    document.getElementById("id_password").focus();
  } else {
    username_field.focus();
  }
  $(".toggle-password").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-eye fa-eye-slash");
    var input = $($(this).attr("toggle"));
    if (input.attr("type") == "password") {
      input.attr("type", "text");
    } else {
      input.attr("type", "password");
    }
  });
  var iam_login_link = document.getElementById("iam_login_link");
  var iam_login_enabled = "False";
  if (iam_login_enabled === 'True') {
    iam_login_link.style.display = ''
  } else {
    iam_login_link.style.display = 'none'
  }
  $('#iamLogin').on('click', function() {
    window.location.href = "/saml-idp/applebananapeach/iam_login/?SAMLRequest=BlaBlaBla";
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>

My question is how can I extract the window.location.href link from that soup ?

In this particular case, the use of BeautifulSoup is not necessarily needed because you need to extract the value from the JavaScript, so you can use a regex:
pattern = r'window\.location\.href\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+)["\']'
match = re.search(pattern, resp.content)

if match:
    
    print(match.group(1))
else:
    print('not found')

